# Need Regular Expressions for asp.net

Tags: regex

I have three text boxes. I need:

1. Regular expression to only allow 3 upper case alphabets. No empty strings and no numbers
2. Regular expression to allow only 3 numbers. no empty strings
3. Regular expression for 5 or fewer uppercase alphabets only. no empty strings, no numbers

Comment: We're not here to do the work for you.  Post what you've tried, what specifically you need help with, etc.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: A handy, on-line, .NET regex util: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
1. ^[A-Z]{3}$
2. ^[0-9]{3}$
3. ^[A-Z]{1,5}$
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I am pretty new to asp.net. I tried using regex.lib.com but was unsuccesfull...thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is a usefull regular expression tool that allows you to build your own regular expressions by selecting options from a form. It will be very easy to create what you have asked for above.